# The $MetaTags(false) variable breaks the page (SilverStripe 3.7.1)

Tags: php, silverstripe

(First of all I'm still trying to figure my way around in SilverStripe so please be gentle)

I'm having a problem with one of the pages on a site where the error is:

**[User Error] Uncaught Error: Call to a member function RelativeLink() on null**

This is happening in **Line 522** in **SiteTree.php** which has not been altered in any way.

```
516         if($this->ParentID && self::config()->nested_urls) {
517             $parent = $this->Parent();
518             // If page is removed select parent from version history (for archive page view)
519             if((!$parent || !$parent->exists()) && $this->IsDeletedFromStage) {
520                 $parent = Versioned::get_latest_version('SiteTree', $this->ParentID);
521             }
522             $base = $parent->RelativeLink($this->URLSegment);
523         } elseif(!$action && $this->URLSegment == RootURLController::get_homepage_link()) {
524             // Unset base for root-level homepages.
525             // Note: Homepages with action parameters (or $action === true)
526             // need to retain their URLSegment.
527             $base = null;
528         }
```

After looking at the stack-trace I figured I would look in the Head.ss file and tried to comment out things in order to narrow down my search. So I found out that if I remove the `$MetaTags(false)` variable in Head.ss everything is working fine.

### Trace:

- **SiteTree->RelativeLink()**
  SiteTree.php:468
- **SiteTree->Link()**
  SiteTree.php:484
- **SiteTree->AbsoluteLink()**
  Translatable.php:1583
- **Translatable->MetaTags(http://silverstripe.org" />  ,,,,,,)**
  Object.php:1068
- **SS_Object->extend(MetaTags,http://silverstripe.org" />  )**
  SiteTree.php:1429
- **SiteTree->MetaTags(false)**
  Object.php:746
- **SS_Object->__call(metatags,Array)**
  ViewableData.php:466
- **ViewableData->obj(MetaTags,Array,,1)**
  ViewableData.php:539
- **ViewableData->XML_val(MetaTags,Array,1)**
  SSViewer.php:187
- **SSViewer_Scope->__call(XML_val,Array)**
  SSViewer.php:650
- **SSViewer_DataPresenter->__call(XML_val,Array)**
  .cache.themes.express.templates.Includes.Head.ss:23
- **include(/var/www/jackon.no/silverstripe-cache/www-data-php7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1/.cache.themes.express.templates.Includes.Head.ss)**
  SSViewer.php:1172
- **SSViewer->includeGeneratedTemplate(/var/www/jackon.no/silverstripe-cache/www-data-php7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1/.cache.themes.express.templates.Includes.Head.ss,Product_Controller,Array,Array,SSViewer_DataPresenter)**
  SSViewer.php:1234
- **SSViewer->process(Product_Controller,Array,SSViewer_DataPresenter)**
  SSViewer.php:1273
- **SSViewer::execute_template(Head,Product_Controller,Array,SSViewer_DataPresenter)** 
  .cache.themes.express.templates.Page.ss:2
- **include(/var/www/jackon.no/silverstripe-cache/www-data-php7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1/.cache.themes.express.templates.Page.ss)**
  SSViewer.php:1172
- **SSViewer->includeGeneratedTemplate(/var/www/jackon.no/silverstripe-cache/www-data-php7.0.30-0ubuntu0.16.04.1/.cache.themes.express.templates.Page.ss,Product_Controller,,Array,)**
  SSViewer.php:1234
- **SSViewer->process(Product_Controller)**
  Controller.php:201
- **Controller->handleAction(SS_HTTPRequest,index)**
  RequestHandler.php:208
- **RequestHandler->handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest,DataModel)**
  Controller.php:151
- **Controller->handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest,DataModel)**
  ContentController.php:174
- **ContentController->handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest,DataModel)**
  ContentController.php:154
- **ContentController->handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest,DataModel)**
  ContentController.php:154
- **ContentController->handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest,DataModel)**
  ModelAsController.php:75
- **ModelAsController->handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest,DataModel)**
  Director.php:385
- **Director::handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest,Session,DataModel)**
  Director.php:149
- **Director::direct(/bygg/jackon-thermomur/thermomur-350-super/,DataModel)**
  main.php:194

There is only one page out of many not working and when I try to see what the `$MetaTags(false)` outputs on one of the working pages it is three `<link rel="alternate" ...>` tags giving a link to the same page in three different languages.

I would love to get some help on how I can locate and fix the problem. I can't really understand how line 522 could go wrong with the if-conditional in line 519.

The page does have a parent and looks exactly the same as a page with the same parent except for changes in the content like text.

Comment: You could debug line 517 and line 520 to check what is being returned in `$parent`. PHP is suggesting it's null. You should be able to access the parent in the way the code is so you may need to debug a bit to work out why it's not working. That being said, there should still be an `if` around line 522 incase the fallback code on line 520 fails as well (which it probably is in your case). That'd be a core change, which pull requests are welcome for! If you're planning on raising this as a GitHub issue on the CMS module please note that it must include reproducible steps

Comment: Thank you @RobbieAverill - I will definitely look into that. And like you say - there might be room for improvement in the core. Maybe I'll end up raising a GitHub issue. Thank you again.